# Вызов перемещающего конструктора

Tags: c++, rvalue

Рассмотрим тест 1:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    string data;
public:
        MyClass()
    { 
        std::cout << "MyClass()" << std::endl; 
    }
    MyClass(string data) : data(data)
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass(string data)"<< std::endl;
    }
    ~MyClass() {}
    MyClass(const MyClass& obj) // copy constr
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass(const MyClass& obj)" << std::endl;
    }
    MyClass(MyClass&& obj) // move constr
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor. MyClass(MyClass&& obj)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj = move(MyClass("privet"));
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    MyClass ob = MyClass("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
MyClass(string data)
Move constructor. MyClass(MyClass&& obj)
-----------------------------
MyClass(string data)
```

Не понимаю почему в строке `MyClass ob = MyClass("hello");` срабатывает вызов только конструктора. Я ожидал увидеть вызов конструктора для временного объекта `MyClass("hello")`, а затем вызов конструктора перемещения для `MyClass ob`, который в качестве параметра принимает `rvalue reference` данного временного объекта, как и в случае с `MyClass obj = move(MyClass("privet"));`

Рассмотрим тест 2:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy ctor\n";
    }

    A(A&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Move ctor\n";
    }
};

void first(A a) {}

void second(A&& a) {}

int main()
{
    first(A{});
    std::cout << "Let's call the second:\n";
    second(A{});
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
A()
Let's call the second:
A()
```

Не понимаю как тут вызываются конструкторы. Почему только по одному на функцию, должны же вызваться по конструктору для временных объектов и, в случае с функцией `first` создание еще одного локального объекта - копии, в случае с функцией `second` без понятия

Comment: Просто оптимизации: зачем создавать два объекта, если достаточно создать один?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы все понимаете правильно, но компилятору разрешается оптимизировать такие вещи. Это называется [*copy elision*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). У GCC есть флаг `-fno-elide-constructors`, который это отключает.

Начиная с C++17 эта оптимизация стала обязательной (*guaranteed copy elision*), так что теперь даже `A a = A(A(A()));` всегда должно быть эквивалентно `A a;`.

---

Еще:

`MyClass(string data) : data(data)` стоит заменить на `MyClass(string data) : data(std::move(data))`.

Comment: Второй тест я взял с вопроса на stackoverflow. Там при вызове `first(A{});` у человека сработал вызов `Move ctor`, что мне совершенно непонятно.

Comment: @Aaas До C++17 эта оптимизация не была обязательной. Скорее всего у человека другой компилятор или флажки для него.